# SQL Server 2016 : upgrade from SP2-GDR to CU15

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I tried to upgrade one of my SQL Server from 2016 SP2-GDR to 2016 SP2 CU15, but I got nothing can be upgraded warning. Is this normal?

The error says:

> There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be updated on this computer.

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What build number is your instance at the moment? (What is the full output of `PRINT @@VERSION;`?)

Comment: @Larnu the build number is 13.0.5103.6

Comment: @Francesco Mantovani   i tried to upgrade from GUI and on the stop of choosing features to upgrade, it won't let me to check anything and it says no upgrades.  I wonder if SP2-GDR can not be upgraded to CU but only new GDR?

Comment: Note that the latest SQL Server SP2 GDR came out after CU15. If that is installed then only CU16 or CU17 would be updates.

Answer (score 0):

The error is general.

It mostly apply to SQL Server Engines or additional packages that [aren't fully updated](https://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=1964) to the latest version.

Go to Windows Update and check if everything is on the latest version.

You can also have an overview of your server this way:

```
DECLARE @props TABLE (propertyname sysname PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @props(propertyname)
SELECT 'BuildClrVersion'
UNION
SELECT 'ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS'
UNION
SELECT 'Edition'
UNION
SELECT 'EditionID'
UNION
SELECT 'EngineEdition'
UNION
SELECT 'LCID'
UNION
SELECT 'LicenseType'
UNION
SELECT 'MachineName'
UNION
SELECT 'NumLicenses'
UNION
SELECT 'ProductVersion'
UNION
SELECT 'ProductLevel'
UNION
SELECT 'ResourceLastUpdateDateTime'
UNION
SELECT 'ResourceVersion'
UNION
SELECT 'ServerName'
SELECT propertyname, SERVERPROPERTY(propertyname) FROM @props
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I found the problem.

Comment: @almali, what was the problem?

Comment: our version is indeed higher than the one that I'm going to upgrade.